# How to convert csv to nested json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, nested-json

I have this csv file and wondering how to display result as expected ?

**CSV File**

```
order_date,customer_id,customername,order_id,total
22/06/2023,1,Allan,5,50
22/06/2023,2,Boy,2,150
```

**Code**

```
import JSON
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str)

def get_nested_rec(key, grp):
    rec = {}
    rec['customer_id'] = key[0]
    rec['customername'] = key[1]
    rec['order_id'] = key[2]
    rec['total'] = key[3]

    return rec

records = []

for key, grp in df.groupby(['customer_id','customername','order_id','total']):
    rec = get_nested_rec(key, grp)
    records.append(rec)

records = dict(data = records)    

print(json.dumps(records, indent=4))
```

**Result**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "customer_id": "A001",
            "customername": "Allan",
            "order_id": "5",
            "total": "50"
        },
        {
            "customer_id": "A002",
            "customername": "Boy",
            "order_id": "2",
            "total": "150"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected result**

```
{
    "order_date":"22/06/2023",
    "data": [
        {
            "customer_id": "A001",
            "customername": "Allan",
            "order_id": "5",
            "total": "50"
        },
        {
            "customer_id": "A002",
            "customername": "Boy",
            "order_id": "2",
            "total": "150"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another easy way to do ? I am new in this Nested JSON. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't see the `data` level, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Set `order_date` as index to transform remaining records as data and use `to_dict` to convert the dataframe as dictionary. Finally, export your result to JSON with `to_json`:

```
records = (df.set_index('order_date').groupby(level='order_date')
             .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
             .rename('data').reset_index()
             .to_json(orient='records', indent=4))
```

Output:

```
>>> records
[
    {
        "order_date":"22\/06\/2023",
        "data":[
            {
                "customer_id":1,
                "customername":"Allan",
                "order_id":5,
                "total":50
            },
            {
                "customer_id":2,
                "customername":"Boy",
                "order_id":2,
                "total":150
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If you have one and only one date, you can use:

```
records = (df.set_index('order_date').groupby(level='order_date')
             .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
             .rename('data').reset_index()
             .squeeze().to_json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```
>>> records
{
    "order_date": "22/06/2023",
    "data": [
        {
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customername": "Allan",
            "order_id": 5,
            "total": 50
        },
        {
            "customer_id": 2,
            "customername": "Boy",
            "order_id": 2,
            "total": 150
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you. I have another question ,  how to remove the square bracket at the beginning ?>>> records

    {
        "order_date":"22\/06\/2023",
        "data":[
            {
                "customer_id":1,
                "customername":"Allan",
                "order_id":5,
                "total":50
            },
            {
                "customer_id":2,
                "customername":"Boy",
                "order_id":2,
                "total":150
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: @jojo. I updated my answer according your request. Added `squeeze()`

Comment: thank you very much,  yes, it works as expected.